# In Magento How to create a new phtml page

Tags: magento

This page needs to accept post contents from another page . How to create a new page which i done now is static which added in admin side CMS page
Is this URL 
app/design/frontend/default/default/template/  ??

Comment: where do you want to add phtml file. in cms page???

Answer (score 1):

This is only for explaining

you need change block type core/template to tag/popular

getLayout()->createBlock('tag/popular')->setTemplate('tag/popular.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>

OR

give a name of block

```
{{block type="core/template" template="theme/home_banner.phtml"  name="myname"}}
```

then

by using xml reference include tags/popular.phtml

create local.xml at app/design/frontend/youupackage/yourtemplate/layout

put this code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<cms_index_index translate="label">
  <reference name="myname">
        <block type="tag/popular" name="home_tags_popular" template="tag/popular.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
</layout>
```

and put below code at home_banner.phtml

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('home_tags_popular');
```